# css selector :first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
div li:first-child
```

what does above css selector target?

1. First li's of every div on the page

or

2. All the descendant li's of the div where div is the first child of its parent

Comment: To comply 2), the CSS should look like `div:first-child li`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `first-child` applies to the `li`. It should select `li`s that are first children under any div.

Answer (score 0):

The first `LI` inside a `DIV`. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/nzxDE/)

Comment: +1 for a link to jsfiddle.net, I hadn't seen that site before but it looks extremely useful

Comment: It's not just "the" first `li` in the `div`. It's any `li` that's the first child of its parent `ul` or `ol` in the `div`. If you add another `ul` into the `div`, you'll see that the first `li` in the second `ul` is also selected.

Answer (score -1):

1) First li's of every div on the page