# css classname :not(:first-child) selector does not exclude the first child of it's classname

Tags: html, css

I need to exclude the first child from a display none rule using  `:not(:first-child)` - see example below:

```css
.child-div {
  background: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.whatever {
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.child-div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="whatever"></div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
```

I was expecting ONE green square but that is not the case. *All are hidden.*

From this: [css selector :first-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433007/css-selector-first-child)

> The first-child applies to the li. It should select lis that are first children under any div.

From this: [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

> the :first-child pseudo-class represents the very first child of its parent. That's it.

`child-div` are the only children in that parent div.

From this: [not:first-child selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289853/notfirst-child-selector/12289888#12289888)

> If you need to support legacy browsers, or if you are hindered by the :not selector's limitation (it only accepts a simple selector as an argument) then you can use another technique:

MDN definition of a "simple selector":

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

I am using a class:

```
<div class="child-div"></div>


.child-div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Howcome I can't select everything except the first child in my example?

I also tried:

[not:first-child selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289853/notfirst-child-selector/26402918#26402918)

`first-of-type` - but had no luck

Comment: **None** of your `.child-div` is a `:first-child`.

Comment: @connexo can you not use :first-child with class names? the first occurance of `.child-div` is under the `whatever` div, I would think that counts as a first child?

Comment: No, there is no `:first-of-class` in CSS. What you want to do cannot be done in current CSS. `:first-child` only cares about what it says - if an element is the **first child** in its parent element. Combining it with a class (or any other selector) only restricts the matches found by `:first-child`.

Comment: :first-child refers to the position of tag in relation to siblings under one parent. I don't see any selector that can match what you wanted. The closest workaround is if the first class is always located as the second child, you can use  .child-div:not(:nth-child(2)) instead

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `:not(:first-child)` on the parent, because you're trying to target the children. There is no "first-child" of the children, because they are the children. I hope that makes sense ;)

```css
.child-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.parent-div > :not(:first-child) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">child-div</div>
  <div class="child-div">child-div</div>
  <div class="child-div">child-div</div>
  <div class="child-div">child-div</div>
  <div class="child-div">child-div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do it by class? I still want to show `whatever`

Answer (score 0):

You are applying it in the wrong way, if I get it right you want to select other than the first child of your parent div so you should do this one :

Edited:
I edited the post to match your comment request, it will select the all child-div class of your parent class except the first one. Good Luck.

```css
.child-div {
  background: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

/*
.parent-div div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
*/

.parent-div > .child-div ~ .child-div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="whatever">Test1</div>
  <div class="child-div">Test2</div>
  <div class="child-div">Test3</div>
  <div class="child-div">Test4</div>
  <div class="child-div">Test5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do it by class? I still want to show `whatever`

Comment: Try this: `div > .child-div ~ .child-div:not(:first-child) { background: yellow; }
`

Comment: No, you can not use first-child as a class selector, the first-child pseudo-class represents the very first child of its parent. I edited my code to match your request.